# redirect() function not working for external URL in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

I want to redirect to www.yahoo.com from my codeIgniter application. I write code like this :
redirect("http://www.yahoo.com");

It is working fine in my local computer (Windows vista / WAMP) but when I upload to linux server it just show blank screen and not redirect.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try using the refresh method:

`redirect('http://www.yahoo.com', 'refresh');`

Comment: Remember guys to do urldecode on your url before redirect, otherwise you will not redirect to that url.

Comment: This is also the same principle for Codeigniter 4 - except its `redirect()->to('external_url',null,'refresh')`. My question is why it doesn't work with auto ... but that is for a different day. Thanks for your answer and direction.

Answer (score 2):

Blank screen normally means a fatal error somewhere. Check your logs!

And check your headers too. Curl it or use a HTTP Client to see what is being returned.

Debugging helps with these things. We are just random people on the internet without access to your computer, so without more information (hell you didnt even mention which version of CI you are using) we are all just taking guesses.

Answer (score 1):

you probably want [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php): `header('location: http://www.yahoo.com');`

Comment: `redirect` is a function defined by CodeIgniter.  See the source here: http://bitbucket.org/ellislab/codeigniter/src/252e9c8091cc/system/helpers/url_helper.php#cl-518

Comment: Ugh, havent used CodeIgniter for about 2 years, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling error_reporting(E_ALL) to see if there are any errors that indicate output is being sent before those headers (specified by redirect()).

A common issue that I find is that the means of uploading (e.g. deploying over FileZilla) will sometimes insert lines depending on the transfer mode I guess. I've seen those same files I uploaded via FileZilla double spaced entirely. More than likely, you have an empty line at the top of your controller. Best way to find out is to edit that controller on the server (e.g. File Editor or re-download and view it) and see if this is the case.